# Convolve Matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, new-operator

I'm tried to make a algorithm to convolve matrix with a kernel, I'm trying to make this in C but I don't understand how can I make this, my code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROW 10
#define COL 10
#define DIV 10


int main(){

  int matrix1[ROW][COL], matrix2[3][3], kernel[3][3], answerx, answery, x, y;

  printf("What is the X coordinates?\n");
  scanf("%i", &answerx);
  printf("What is the Y coordinates?\n");
  scanf("%i", &answery);

  // Generate Kernel
  for(int r=0;r<3;r++){
    for(int c=0;c<3;c++){
      kernel[r][c]=rand()%DIV;
      }
  }

  // Generate User Matrix
  for(int r=0;r<ROW;r++){
    for(int c=0;c<COL;c++){
      matrix1[r][c]=rand()%DIV;
      }
  }

  x=answerx-1;
  y=answery-1;

  // Generate Matrix with Kernel
  for(int r=0;r<3;r++){
    for(int c=0;c<3;c++){
      matrix2[r][c]=matrix1[x][y]*kernel[r][c];
      }
    }
  }

  // Print Kernel
  printf("\tKernel(Filter)\n");

  for(int r=0;r<3;r++){
    for(int c=0;c<3;c++){
      printf("\t %i", kernel[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  // Print User Matrix
  printf("\t User Matrix \n");

  for(int r=0;r<ROW;r++){
    for(int c=0;c<COL;c++){
      printf("\t %i", matrix1[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  // Print Kernel-Matrix
  printf("\t Kernel/Matrix \n");

  for(int r=0;r<3;r++){
    for(int c=0;c<3;c++){
      printf("\t %i", matrix2[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("Coordiantes X: %i e Y: %i \n", answerx, answery);
}
```

I'm really new in programmation, this is a exercise of my graduation, but I can't understand, how can I control the kernel with r and c with an x and y, I'm really needed a answer

Comment: Do you know from a mathematical standpoint what you want to do?  For example, could you edit the question to write out (in matrix notation) exactly what you want to compute from the matrix *M*, for people not familiar with convolution.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm gonna make this question more easy to understand

Comment: You can use `x` and `y`, but when used with `matrix` you must validate `0 <= x < ROW` and `0 <= y < COL` for `matrix2` you must validate `0 <= x < 3` and the same for `y`. What is it that your are having trouble with using `x` and `y`?

Comment: Writing a smaller program specially compute only `matrix2[0][0]` maybe helpful to understand how to compute entire `matrix2`.

Answer (score 1):

The discrete [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) of a 2D array with a kernel results in another 2D array:

```
out[x, y] = sum_j sum_k kernel[j, k] * in[x - j, y - k].
```

where the sums over j and k are over the nonzero footprint of the kernel. This is the computation that you want to implement.

Note that `in[x - j, y - k]` might at some points refer to out-of-bounds elements where the input array isn't defined. So usually a method of [boundary handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Edge_Handling) is needed, like assuming that out-of-bounds elements are zero or some extrapolation of the input.

You might find it helpful to look at how signal processing libraries approach convolution. How they represent inputs and outputs, boundary options, and such:

- [Matlab's conv2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)
- [scipy.signal.convolve2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)